# Integrate a COM object in a C++ CLR Console App

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am trying to use a COM object in a C++ CLR Console App as I did in C#. (it comes from statconn) I am new with the C++ CLR code and I don't find sample explaining how it works
I did the following things:

```
using namespace StatConnTools;
using namespace StatConnControls;
using namespace StatConnectorCommonLib;
using namespace STATCONNECTORSRVLib;
STATCONNECTORSRVLib::StatConnector^ oStatCon = gcnew  STATCONNECTORSRVLib::StatConnector();
oStatCon::IStatConnector::Init(L"R");
oStatCon::IStatConnector::Close();
```

I get the message : oStatConn must be a class or namespace when followed by ::

thanks for help

Comment: These are *statements*, you must move them into a function.

Comment: Can I ask how you added the com object to your project?  I'm also trying to get StatConn to work from unmanaged c++ with no luck so far.  I tried #import "StatConnectorSrv.exe" and #import "StatConnectorSrv.tlb" but StatConnector is a struct, not an object.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `oStatCon` is an object, i.e. an *instance* of a class. The scope operator can only be used on namespaces or classes, like the error message says.

You should be calling `Init` and `Close` as normal functions:

```
oStatCon.Init(L"R");
oStatCon.Close();
```

Comment: thanks you Joachim, this is what I tried at the begining but I didn't get the methods of the object, in fact the declaration is StatConnect oSatConn = gc new SatsConnect() and then oStatCon->Init(..) thanks you again